# Pass data from DB to React component

Tags: django, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to code the UI for our comments app,

(project repo https://github.com/Lv-246Python/myTrip)

and i just can't get how i should structure my React components and what's the flow for getting real comments from DB to be rendered. I know i have to use 'axios' but how do i code that "this is field is going to be filled with what 'axios' gives you"?

Here's my code below and if you need more my current branch is (33-comment-react-component), thanks.

**comment.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import List from 'material-ui/List/List';

import {CommentItem} from './comment_item';
import {CommentForm} from './comment_form';

const styles = {
  paper: {
      paddingLeft: 15,
      paddingRight: 15,
      paddingBottom: 15,

      marginLeft: 15,
      marginRight: 15,
      marginBottom: 15
  },

  divider: {
      backgroundColor: 'grey'
  }

};

export default class Comment extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Paper zDepth={5} rounded={false} style={styles.paper}>
                <div>
                    <List>
                        <CommentItem/>
                        <CommentItem/>
                    </List>

                    <Divider style={styles.divider}/>
                    <CommentForm/>
                </div>
            </Paper>
        );
    }
}
```

**comment_item.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import {Card, CardActions, CardHeader, CardText} from 'material-ui/Card';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import ListItem from 'material-ui/List/ListItem';


const styles = {
  avatar: {
      marginRight: 10,
      marginBottom: 10
  },

  commentText: {
      fontSize: 20
  },

};

export class CommentItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ListItem>
                <Card>
                    <CardHeader
                        title="Roman Hrytskiv"
                        subtitle="29/07/2017"
                        expandable={true} />

                    <CardText
                        actAsExpander={true}
                        style={styles.commentText}>
                        <UserAvatar />
                        Nice views man!
                        <br />
                        I wish I could go there with you but i have to code. See you in a month!
                    </CardText>

                    <CardActions
                        expandable={true}>
                      <FlatButton label="Edit" />
                      <FlatButton label="Delete" />
                    </CardActions>

                </Card>
            </ListItem>
        );
    }
}

class UserAvatar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<Avatar src="static/src/img/avatar.jpg" size={40} style={styles.avatar}/>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have to create REST API and receive  data using GET requests. You can create REST API for django app using django rest framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider going over the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/) of react once again and try to get the concept of [state and props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). When the app loads up you need to make an API request to get data from your REST API that you might have created. Then after the request is successful you need to set state with that data and then use that state to view data onto the components. You must once read about the lifecycle methods of react and which function to call at what point of time. 
Later on once you get going through the react architecture and know its lifecycle methods you must consider learning about [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux).

[This](https://www.udemy.com/react-redux/) is the best online course I found for learning react and redux. You can consider checking it in case of doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Flux` architecture. You can choose pure `Flux` (Facebook `Flux utils`) or some framework based on `Flux`. I personally recommend `Redux`.

Since `React` is not a framework it doesn't explain such things, but `Redux` (or similar) will help you.

It will take some time to understand Flux/Redux flow, but it worths it.